# Eloquent updateOrInsert

Tags: eloquent

I would like the eloquent to be able to auto-feed the created_at and updated_at fields, using the following commands below

```
                DB::table('partida')->updateOrInsert(
                    [
                        'rodada' => $values->rodada,
                        'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
                        'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id
                    ],
                    [
                        'partida_id' => $key,
                        'rodada' => $values->rodada,
                        'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
                        'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id,
                        'partida_data' => (string)$value->partida_data,
                        'placar_mandante' => $value->placar_oficial_mandante,
                        'placar_visitante' => $value->placar_oficial_visitante,
                        'local' => (string)$value->local
                    ]
                );
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to use the Eloquent methods properly, use Eloquent and not the query builder.

You can practically do the same with the `updateOrCreate()` method, which will set the timestamps if the model defines them.

You'll get something like (assuming the Partida model exists):

```
Partida::updateOrCreate([
        'rodada' => $values->rodada,
        'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
        'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id
    ],
    [
        'partida_id' => $key,
        'rodada' => $values->rodada,
        'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
        'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id,
        'partida_data' => (string)$value->partida_data,
        'placar_mandante' => $value->placar_oficial_mandante,
        'placar_visitante' => $value->placar_oficial_visitante,
        'local' => (string)$value->local
    ]);
```

Comment: What if you have a table with a composite primary key? Then you cannot use Eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use the `upsert()` method.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#upserts

Answer (score -4):

What you want is a part **Eloquent**. Though you are using **Query Builder**

If you want to continue using Query Builder I suggest you append the following in your array.

```
                DB::table('partida')->updateOrInsert(
                [
                    'rodada' => $values->rodada,
                    'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
                    'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id,
                    'created_at' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
                ],
                [
                    'partida_id' => $key,
                    'rodada' => $values->rodada,
                    'mandante_fk' => $value->clube_casa_id,
                    'visitante_fk' => $value->clube_visitante_id,
                    'partida_data' => (string)$value->partida_data,
                    'placar_mandante' => $value->placar_oficial_mandante,
                    'placar_visitante' => $value->placar_oficial_visitante,
                    'local' => (string)$value->local,
                    'created_at' =>  \Carbon\Carbon::now(),
                    'updated_at' => \Carbon\Carbon::now()
                ]
            );
```

Comment: You can't put created_at and updated_at to the first array, because it will always create new record.. (by always i mean, except that case, if you will try to do this several times per second :) )